# Where does try_to_wake_up() add the task to the CPU run queue?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've been trying to understand the [try_to_wake_up() function in the linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2516) somewhat better. Conceptually, I (think) that to wake up a process we must be adding it to the CPU runqueue, but I have trouble seeing where this is occurring.

```
    //try_to_wake_up()

    if (p == current) {
        /* I omitted some comments here*/

        success = 1;
        cpu = task_cpu(p);        //task_cpu(p) returns READ_ONCE(p->cpu);
        trace_sched_waking(p);    //This is just a logging call
        p->state = TASK_RUNNING; 
        trace_sched_wakeup(p);    //Another logging call
        goto out;
    }
```

So [task_cpu()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1813) doesn't seem to be modifying the CPU runqueue at all, so I decide to go look at the label out, which is calling [ttwu_stat()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2175):

```
/*I omitted some intermediate code here*/
out:
    if (success)
        ttwu_stat(p, cpu, wake_flags);
    preempt_enable();

    return success;
```

But then when I go look at [ttwu_stat()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2175), it just seems to be a bunch of calls to this [__schedstat_inc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/sched/stats.h#L34) macro that just increments its input argument.

So... where are we actually adding the task_struct* p to the CPU run queue?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `p == current` a special case?  What does that function do if that condition isn't true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block you’ve quoted is a special case, as explained in the elided comments:

```c
         * We're waking current, this means 'p->on_rq' and 'task_cpu(p)
         * == smp_processor_id()'. Together this means we can special
         * case the whole 'p->on_rq && ttwu_remote()' case below
         * without taking any locks.
```

Since the task to awake is the current task, it’s already on a run queue (`p->on_rq`) so it doesn’t need to be added to one.

Adding a task to a run queue is dealt with [further down](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2627):

```c
    cpu = select_task_rq(p, p->wake_cpu, SD_BALANCE_WAKE, wake_flags);
```

This adds the task to a run queue and returns the CPU on which it is scheduled, so migration can be dealt with if necessary.

The `#ifdef CONFIG_SMP` condition merits some explanation: if SMP isn’t supported, then multiple tasks *can’t* run concurrently, and since we know we’re not waking the current task, the only scenario to deal with is I/O wait.